# How to replace a character in a string contating '\x'?

Tags: python, string, pyserial

**Target:** Remove `'\x'` from string.

`split()`, `strip()`, and `replace()` all give the same error.

Can anyone help me out?

```
my_list = '\x00\x06\x00'
my_list.replace('\x', '')
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

Comment: The errors are because it thinks you are trying to remove _part_ of a character. These characters in the string look like hex codes, so `\x00` and `\x06` are single characters. You can't remove the `\x` from them, but you can replace `\x00` with another character.

Comment: `'\x'` is not a string. `r'\x'` is, but then it is not in `my_list` so  after removing it you will have the same string. Is `''.join(format(ord(x), '0>2d') for x in my_list)` what you want? Why is a string assigned to a variable called `my_list`? I am under the impression that you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1):

The default string literal in Python considers backslash as an escape character.

To interpret backslash literally, use `r'my string with \x in it'`, so try:

```
my_list.replace(r'\x', '')
```

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

[What exactly do "u" and "r" string flags do, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an `r` before the `'\x'` in `replace()`  as well as the string. That will tell python that `\` should be interpreted as a character and not as an escape character.

```
my_list = r'\x00\x06\x00'
my_list.replace(r'\x', '')
```